# How to configure VPN using pcf profile and custom certificate

Tags: vpn, certificates

I want to connect the VPN of my university with my Android device.

My university provides a .pem certificate, a .pcf profile and [instructions](http://www.rz.uni-konstanz.de/en/our-offers/internetzugang/remote-access/gnulinux/) how to set up the vpn connection under a "normal" GNU/Linux distribution - on Arch Linux this works perfectly.

On my Android phone I tried the built-in connection manager and the "anyconnect ics+" app by Cisco, but I'm stuck:

Basically I can't import the profile: the built-in app doesn't provide any form for this; the Cisco app only allows xml-profiles (which is strange as I want to use a Cisco technology...).

The Cisco client doesn't even allow me to import the certificate: when importing it asks for a password, but I don't know why. For the built-in app I could convert the .pem to a .crt file (issuing the command `openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in chain-dtag-dfn-uni.pem -out chain-dtag-dfn-uni.crt`) and import the converted certificate.

Do you know other ways or other apps that allow me to connect to the VPN?

(I use Android 4.4.2 on a Samsung SIII Neo.)

Comment: Is your device rooted? Then it would be possible to add the certificate as "trusted system certificate". Alternatively, you could try a different [VPN app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_vpn).